# Removing special characters from filenames in multiple subdirectories in Python

Tags: python, batch-rename

I have a root directory called `rootDir`, and under that multiple sub-directories called `subDir1`, `subdir2`, etc.

All sub-directories contain hundreds of files. I would like to remove some special (bad) characters from the filenames, lets say an array of characters e.g. `bad_chars = [ '(',')','{','}' ]`.

What is an elegant way to do this efficiently in Python?

---

I thought I would make use of the `os.walk()` function and iterate over all the sub-directories but I couldn't really figure how to do it a short way.

Ideally, I would have a function like this, which takes the path of the `rootDir` and array of bad characters as input:

```
def(rootDir, bad_chars):
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `os.walk` is a reasonable approach.

You'll need to refine your specifications somewhat, though:

- Do you want to rename directories *and* files, or only files?  (For instance, given `'('` as a character-to-be-removed, what do you do with the path `'this(/that'`?  The file name is fine, but the directory name has one of the bad characters.)
- What do you do if renaming a file (or directory) would result in a collision?  For instance, suppose you find a file named `'this('` but there is already a file named `'this'` (no parenthesis)?

Aside from both of these issues, [the method Hackaholic just posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33300179/1256452) looks good.

Comment: I just have a problem with the filenames containing such characters, because I process the files further with another software which seems to skip the files that contain certain characters.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `os.walk` as you mentioned:

```
for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        os.rename(os.path.join(dir,file), os.path.join(dir, "".join(filter(lambda x:x not in bad_chars, file))))
```

Comment: Apart from the problem of not checking for collisions with existing names, this code calls `os.rename` even if the filename is unchanged, which is rather inefficient: system calls (like rename) aren't particularly fast.

Comment: Not previous commenter, but this is pretty trivial to fix: replace `os.rename` with `def rename(a, b): if a != b: os.rename(a, b)` and then use `rename`.  Or if you want to be overly clever, `(lambda a, b: None if a = b else os.rename(a, b))(os.path.join(...), ...)` :-)

Comment: I didn't say "don't use `os.rename`". I'm saying don't call rename if the new filename is identical to the old filename, since it's pointless. And don't call rename if there's already a file with the new name.

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename): "`os.rename(src, dst)` Rename the file or directory `src` to `dst`. If `dst` is a directory, `OSError` will be raised. On Unix, if `dst` exists and is a file, it will be replaced silently if the user has permission. [...] On Windows, if `dst` already exists, `OSError` will be raised even if it is a file". The Python 3 docs are similar except that `os.rename` also accepts a couple of directory descriptor args.